# Aurelia Kendo Grid - Search bar not displaying

Tags: aurelia, kendo-ui-grid

Using Aurelia and Kendo UI, how do you get the search bar to display?

I want this:

[image]

But I'm getting this:

[image]

I want to display the search bar, but I'm getting a 'search' button.

Kendo documentation: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/search.fields

**My example: https://gist.run?id=ede27170780f6d9116808aab52cf5b68**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="aurelia-kendoui-bridge/grid/grid"></require>
  <require from="aurelia-kendoui-bridge/grid/col"></require>

  <ak-grid k-data-source.bind="datasource"
           k-toolbar.bind="['search']">
    <ak-col k-title="name" k-field="name"></ak-col>
    <ak-col k-title="age" k-field="age"></ak-col>
  </ak-grid>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.datasource = {
      data: [
          { name: "Jane", age: 30 }, 
          { name: "John", age: 33 }
      ],
      schema: {
          model: {
              fields: {
                  name: { },
                  age: { type: "number" }
              }
          }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using an old version of kenko ui.

updated the versions, seems to be working:

https://gist.run/?id=69af4f41d3606134e38741d54294330a